# PHP extension paths are being escaped automatically

Tags: php, apache

Ok, just as the title explains.  I am running an apache 2.2 server with php 5.3.  When I load php extensions, the path to the extension folder is being escaped i.e. an extra slash is being added to the path and therefore the extensions are not being found.

This is crazy.  magic quotes are off.

Please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a windows machine?

If so, double check you have added your php directory to the PATH

You will find some instructions here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

In extremis, try to do it manually..

or maybe, your installation is not adapted. (Wrong configuration)